# Why can't I use the result of a static constexpr in the declaration of another function in a class?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is my barebones code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

class cColor {
  public:
  enum eValue { k_Red, k_Green, k_Blue };
  static constexpr std::size_t NumValues() { return 3; }
  static constexpr std::array<eValue, NumValues()> Values()  { return {k_Red, k_Green, k_Blue}; }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "NumColors=" << cColor::NumValues() << '\n';
}
```

I'm trying to declare `Values()` as a static constexpr and I thought I should be able to use `NumValues()` as it's a static constexpr as well. However, this program [fails to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/EGyU5N) and throws this error:

```
main.cpp:8:39: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
  static constexpr std::array<eValue, NumValues()> Values()  { return {k_Red, k_Green, k_Blue}; }
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:8:39: note: undefined function 'NumValues' cannot be used in a constant expression
main.cpp:7:32: note: declared here
  static constexpr std::size_t NumValues() { return 3; }
```

However, if I use a static constexpr member variable it [works just fine](https://godbolt.org/z/TZDZjX).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

class cColor {
  public:
  enum eValue { k_Red, k_Green, k_Blue };
  static constexpr std::size_t NumValues {3};
  static constexpr std::array<eValue, NumValues> Values()  { return {k_Red, k_Green, k_Blue}; }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "NumColors=" << cColor::NumValues << '\n';
}
```

So what is it about a static constexpr member function that prevents the code from compiling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because it's in a class definition. You can't use the static functions of a class at compile time until after the full definition of the class.

If the reason is unclear, your code is actually this:

```cpp
class cColor {
  public:
  enum eValue { k_Red, k_Green, k_Blue };
  static constexpr std::size_t NumValues() { return 3; }
  static constexpr std::array<cColor::eValue, cColor::NumValues()> Values()  { return {k_Red, k_Green, k_Blue}; }
};
```

You see, when you say `std::array<cColor::eValue, cColor::NumValues()>` as the return type, you're using `cColor::NumValues()`, which uses `cColor` which has not yet been defined (because it's inside the class definition.

You're effectively defining a component of `cColor` in terms of itself.

The problem is solved by moving the self-referential component outside of the class (one or both of them):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

static constexpr std::size_t NumValues() { return 3; }

class cColor {
  public:
  enum eValue { k_Red, k_Green, k_Blue };

  static constexpr std::array<eValue, NumValues()> Values()  { return {k_Red, k_Green, k_Blue}; }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "NumColors=" << NumValues() << '\n';
}
```

**Edit:**

To further answer your question as to why specifically the use of a constexpr function is causing problems (as opposed to your revised question using a constexpr variable), I'll give this next piece of information:

Have you ever noticed that you can't use a function before it's declared, but you can use a member function before it's declared (in the class definition I mean).

That's because the C++ compiler glosses over the entire class, including the member/static variables and methods/static methods before it does anything else. Therefore the methods/static methods (which I'll collectively refer to as member functions) must have well-formed declarations prior to having any of their actual implementation defined - this of course includes their return types.

Thus, at compile time, when the declaration for `Values()` is examined, it knows the return type depends on `NumValues()`, and it knows `NumValues()` returns `std::size_t`, but it hasn't yet examined the implementation of any member functions in the class yet. Thus it doesn't know (yet) that `NumValues()` will return `3`.

Thus, you can also solve this problem by using delayed return type deduction. The real crux of the problem is that `Values()` must have a well-formed return type before the implementation of its class's member functions are inspected.

Here's another solution that might illuminate the specifics of the problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

class cColor {
  public:
  enum eValue { k_Red, k_Green, k_Blue };
  static constexpr std::size_t NumValues() { return 3; }
  static constexpr auto Values() { return std::array<eValue, NumValues()>{k_Red, k_Green, k_Blue}; }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "NumColors=" << cColor::NumValues() << '\n';
}
```

You see, `auto` is a valid return type for the signature, and the actual return type is deduced from the method implementation, which at that point knows the implementation of `NumValues()`.

The reason for this weird compiler parsing order is so that you don't have to arrange methods in a certain order for them to compile *(under normal circumstances - read on)*. This way all methods are known prior to any implementations, which is *sort of* like having a forward declaration for every method in the class.

And just if you were wondering, yes, moving the definition/declaration of `NumValues()` to be after `Values()` will cause a compilation failure because our trick doesn't work anymore since the implementation for `NumValues()` is examined after the implementation for `Values()` and thus `Values()` doesn't know `NumValues()` returns `3`:

```cpp
class cColor {
  public:
  enum eValue { k_Red, k_Green, k_Blue };

  // THIS ORDERING FAILS TO COMPILE
  static constexpr auto Values() { return std::array<eValue, NumValues()>{k_Red, k_Green, k_Blue}; }
  static constexpr std::size_t NumValues() { return 3; }
};
```

Your example works because constexpr variables must be defined and declared at the same time, so the value of `3` is known at that point onward and thus makes the declarations valid. However, if you move the declaration/definition of the static constexpr member variable to be after `Values()` you again have a compile error which can be fixed by using the `auto` hack I demonstrated above.

```cpp
class cColor {
  public:
  enum eValue { k_Red, k_Green, k_Blue };

  // THIS ORDERING FAILS TO COMPILE
  static constexpr std::array<eValue, NumValues> Values() { return {k_Red, k_Green, k_Blue}; }
  static constexpr std::size_t NumValues = 3;
};
```

```cpp
class cColor {
  public:
  enum eValue { k_Red, k_Green, k_Blue };

  // AUTO TRICK MAKES THIS WORK
  static constexpr auto Values() { return std::array<eValue, NumValues>{k_Red, k_Green, k_Blue}; }
  static constexpr std::size_t NumValues = 3;
};
```

Comment: Ah, it makes sense when you put it that way. Thanks

Comment: On second thought, why does a static constexpr member variable work but not a static constexpr member function. I was playing around with this some more and I've updated my question with an example of code that works

Comment: Seems like a very poor diagnostic if this is the cause

Comment: Oh, "undefined function" buried on the second output never mind :D

Comment: @kshenoy ok, I've updated my answer with information specifically addressing that issue. That was actually a really important point that I forgot to include originally (the "why", as it were).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Jean and my apologies for switching out the original question under you but I didn't think it right to split it into two separate functions when they seemed so related.

Comment: @kshenoy Well you're right, the first time around I probably should have included an alternative to relocating the functions anyway. I think it has some good alternatives now. Happy C++ing!