# constexpr function call doesn't compile

Tags: c++

Why the code below does not compile?

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <array>

class A
{
    struct Helper
    {
        static constexpr uint64_t p2(uint8_t n)
        {
            return static_cast<uint64_t>(1) << n;
        }
    };

    using DenomArray = std::array<uint64_t, Helper::p2(5)>;
};
```

With GCC I get:

```
error: 'static constexpr uint64_t A::Helper::p2(uint8_t)' called in a constant expression before its definition is complete
```

My understanding was that `p2` function should be defined because `Helper` class is fully compiled.

Tried MSVC Compiler Version 19.29.30040 for x86 and GCC 12.

**EDIT1:**

template and non-template classes behaves differently. For example the code below compiles:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
private:

    struct Helper
    {
        static constexpr T p2(uint8_t n)
        {
            return static_cast<T>(1) << n;
        }
    };

    using DenomArray = std::array<T, Helper::p2(5)>;
};

using IntA = A<uint64_t>;
```

Comment: You should specify which version of C++ you're using (i.e. c++11, c++14...)

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: The definition of an inline class function is not part of the class's definition.  Because of that, they are not usable in defining members of the class.

Comment: @AlexisWilke see updated post.

Comment: I've reopened the Q, here is a link to the old target for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799393/why-cant-i-use-the-result-of-a-static-constexpr-in-the-declaration-of-another-f.  Not sure which compiler is right here as `Helper::p2(5)` is actually `A::Helper::p2(5)`, and `A` has yet to be defined.

Answer (score 2):

The place where you define `DenomArray` is where `A::Helper` is not yet fully defined, and this makes `A::Helper::p2(5)` non constant expression.

The interesting thing is that making `A` a template fixes this problem - which is probably a language defect - see here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1626

More formally: https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#2

> A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a
> converted constant expression ([expr.const]) of the type of the
> template-parameter.

then https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5:

> An expression E is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of
> E, following the rules of the abstract machine ([intro.execution]),
> would evaluate one of the following:

and now to the part which you code violates: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.3

> (5.3) an invocation of an undefined constexpr function;

why its undefined? - because its used in a context which is regarded as a non complete context:

https://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem.general-7

> A complete-class context of a class (template) is a
> (7.1) function body ([dcl.fct.def.general]),
> (7.2) default argument ([dcl.fct.default]),
> (7.3) default template argument ([temp.param]),
> (7.4) noexcept-specifier ([except.spec]), or (7.5) default member
> initializer

so its not said that the body of a `struct` is a complete-class context. You could place your `using` inside a function body, and it would compile:

```
class A
{
    struct Helper
    {
        static constexpr uint64_t p2(uint8_t n)
        {
            return static_cast<uint64_t>(1) << n;
        }
    };
   void ff() {
     using DenomArray = std::array<uint64_t, Helper::p2(5)>;
   }
};
```

[edit]
also, see here: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6536fdbe1ded1d01, clang error is different from gcc as it says `Helper::p2(5)` is non constexpr :

> error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression

which is what I explained above.